# my book's implementation of insertion sort in C

Tags: c, implementation, insertion-sort

I want to know exactly what the 3rd parameter is supposed to be because I've never seen anything like it.

```
void sortPointers(void **ar, int n, int (*cmp)(const void *, const void *))
{
    int j;
    for (j = 1; j < n; j++)
    {
        int i = j - 1;
        int *value = ar[j];
        while (i >= 0 && cmp(ar[i], value) > 0)
        {
            ar[i+1] = ar[i];
            i--;
        }
        ar[i+1] = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a function pointer. Now you should know what to research.

Comment: The third parameter is a (pointer to a) comparison function that takes two elements to be sorted and compares them. If the elements are in order, a negative number (or 0 in case of equality) is given. If the elements are in the wrong order, give a positive result and they will be swapped. That is, its output should be similar to `strcmp`.

Comment: Checkout [`qsort` documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort). It has `cmp` as an argument that serves the same purpose.

Comment: `void**` uh oh... @zac Can you provide the title of that book, or even better, show how the sort function is actually called?

Comment: It is the address of a function that will compare two elements so as to perform the sort. The function may be one you implement or some other function that is provided for you. The function must comply to the prototype as shown.

Comment: @2501 The book is "Algorithms in a Nutshell" by George T. Heineman, Gary Pollice, and Stanley Selkow. It doesn't even show the function being called, just how the algorithm is implemented in a certain language.

Thanks for your answers guys.

Comment: @Zac Thanks. Too bad they don't show how the pointer sorting is done, as many readers will implement it incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That argument is the pointer to a function which does comparison of two void* pointers. This way of implementation of the sortPointers(..) function makes it possible for its caller to use any comparison function, thus adding that flexibility.

http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex18.html

Comment: "comparison of two void* pointers" - wrong. It is for comparison of two objects of any generic type pointed by these pointers.

Comment: @EugeneSh.Resmy is correct. It is also correct that those void pointers may be pointing to different types.